# Increase JUST font size in css for mobiles, without setting a viewport

Tags: css

Normally when I am creating a responsive site, I do the normal thing of setting a viewport to the device width, and creating different layouts for different screen resolutions.

But I'm doing a few tweaks to an old site that has big chunky buttons, default font sizes and a simple layout, and actually it looks quite usable when viewed as a desktop-style fixed-width layout, even on small mobile devices.

Rather than specifying a viewport and completely rewriting all the css to make a series of mobile-friendly versions, I'd really like to just increase the main body element font size a little more for viewing on a screen that is physically small: for this particular layout, this would be very usable - if I could work out how to do it!

Is this what -webkit-text-size-adjust: is for?  It seems like it should be an easy thing to tweak, but all my googling turns up full responsive design approaches, which are overkill for this particular small task.

Comment: why not use `@media (max-device-width...`

Comment: Why do you not want to use a viewport? This is what it's for.

Comment: DA is right - I didn't think this through.  I was thinking that I didn't want to set a viewport, because the behaviour without one was what I wanted - ie, a desktop-style presentation.

But in fact, what I should have done was set the viewport to the same fixed width that my site was already using, and then use @media (max-device-width) to change the font size for situations where the screen size was diddy.

Sigh.  Is there a 'This Was The Wrong Question' button?  Thanks to PeterVR and DA for asking the right questions and helping me see this!

Answer (score 0):

A way to make it is to detect the screen width with javascript using the `window.screen.width` property, and then apply the styles that you want from there.

Here's an example using jquery, however the same can be achieved with native javascript if you don't want to use a library http://jsfiddle.net/UXV7Z/

You can apply as many filters in resolution as you need, just like you would using media queries

Comment: This would also have worked, but in the end I thought more carefully about how viewports work, and was able to use a fixed-width one although I had originally thought that was what I wanted to avoid.

Sorry for the slightly misleading question!

Answer (score 0):

DONT use javascript for such a simple task to accomplish with modern CSS, just use:

```
font-size: calc(80px - 3vw);
```

and adjust the values accordingly. That will icrease the size on smaller devices and decrease it on wider devices, which makes sense for buttons and footers and what not, but if you want to decrease the size on smaller width screens for text like large titles that overflow just use:

```
font-size: calc(25px + 0.35vw);
```

Once again adjust the values to fit your needs. And see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) to view the browser support for the CSS calc() function. All modern updated browsers support it